# Has it been revealed how many MCU projects Evan Peters' contract is?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

Main reason I ask is due to people like Tom Holland. When he was contracted by Marvel, it was for 3 solo Spider-Man films, and then 3 appearances in other films (these being *Captain America: Civil War*, *Avengers: Infinity War*, & *Avengers: Endgame*).

I was curious, has there been any similar contract revealed for Evan Peters? After all, *Multiverse of Madness* could theoretically bring him in from the multiverse.

Comment: Given what his character has so far been in WandaVision there’s no reason to assume he’ll be in anymore films/shows but of course that’s not to say it won’t happen.

Comment: Which is precisely why I'm asking regarding the contract.

Comment: No contract spoilers!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite-If you don't want contract spoilers, then don't be viewing questions like these.

Answer (score 2):

All signs point to this being a single appearance with no (contractual) commitment for follow-ups beyond the usual requirements to do marketing and not badmouth the show. No additional MCU projects have been announced that involve him, although he's said that he's open to the idea and enjoyed working on the show.

His role is described (by WandaVision creator and showrunner Jac Schaeffer) as a fakeout.

> It was always the intention that Evan be fake Pietro. **That he was not,
> in fact, the MCU Quicksilver.** Then beyond that, I can't actually
> remember when those decisions were made. It was very early tied to his
> storyline that he was Agatha's puppet. He was a young man living
> nearby; she had taken over his house and was holding him hostage. We
> really loved it. It was at the service of Agatha's character, because
> we loved the idea that every time she would complain about her
> husband, she was actually speaking out loud about the man she was
> holding hostage. It's just so mean; it's so mean.
>
> <sub><sup>[WandaVision's Evan Peters Was Never Meant To Become The MCU's Quicksilver](https://screenrant.com/wandavision-evan-peters-mcu-casting-plans/)</sup></sub>